# CCKNavDrawer reload table data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using [CCKNavDrawer](https://github.com/calvinchankf/CCKFNavDrawer) as my application's side menu. The menu is working perfectly but I am unable to reload the table created within the `DrawerView.xib` view.

The code snippet is as follows:

`CCKFNavDrawer.m`

```
- (void)drawerToggle
{
    if (!self.isOpen) {
        [self setupTable];
        [self openNavigationDrawer];
    }else{
        [self closeNavigationDrawer];
    }
}

-(void)setupTable {
    DrawerView *dv = [[DrawerView alloc]init];
    arrMenus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:SINGLETONSHARED.arrCats];
    [dv.drawerTableView reloadData];
}
```

What I am doing is reloading the table every time user toggles Menu Drawer(not a good approach though).
But the `reloadData` is not reloading the table with new array stored in singleton variable `arrCats`.

You guys can simple download and run the sample app and test the above condition.

Kindly ask me if more details required.

Help!

Comment: Guys....please mention in comments if my question is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feel so naive now.

No need to create instance of drawer view:

```
DrawerView *dv = [[DrawerView alloc]init];
```

Just use already created `self.drawerView`

So the setupTable Method will look like:

```
-(void)setupTable {
    arrMenus = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:SINGLETONSHARED.arrCats];
    [self.drawerView.drawerTableView reloadData];
}
```

Done!